# C - Passing function with unknown params to another function, and calling it

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameters

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
void sum(int a, int b){ printf("result: %d", a+b); }

void callFunc(void (*funct)(...), ...)
{
     va_list ars;

     va_start(ars, funct);
     funct(ars);
     va_end(ars);
}

int main()
{
     callFunc(sum, 2,3);         

     return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't work, because of needing of two `va_list`s, for `funct` params and arguments passed. However, even if i try to pass the sum function, it says:`error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(int, int)' to 'void (*)(...)'`

So how to make this work good old C-style?

Comment: Why did you tag this C++ if you want to keep it to C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it like that. It's just simply not possible.

The best you can do (while keeping it generic) is change `funct` to take a `va_list`, much like [`vprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/vfprintf). But that probably won't work very well for your purposes.

Alternatively, you can do a macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CALL_FUNC(func, ...) func(__VA_ARGS__)

void sum(int a, int b){ printf("result: %d", a+b); }

int main()
{
     CALL_FUNC(sum, 2, 3);         

     return 0;
}
```